# passing a list of string from first page to second page

Tags: arrays, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How do I pass a list of strings(contains a URL strings that is stored in my firestore) in another page? here's my MaterialPageRoute that I am using to pass the other data other than the list of strings which are String data types only.

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
// * I am passing it to MerchantEditProduct page
                                  builder: (context) => MerchantEditProduct(
                                          latestprod: ProductModel(
                                        couponNameCtrlr:
                                            getProductDetails.couponNameCtrlr,
                                        couponTypeCtrlr:
                                            getProductDetails.couponTypeCtrlr,
                                        couponDescCtrlr:
                                            getProductDetails.couponDescCtrlr,
                                        couponSalePriceCtrlr: getProductDetails
                                            .couponSalePriceCtrlr,
                                        couponUniqueId:
                                            getProductDetails.couponUniqueId,
                                        couponCategoryCtrlr: getProductDetails
                                            .couponCategoryCtrlr,
                                        couponOrigPriceCtrlr: getProductDetails
                                            .couponOrigPriceCtrlr,
                                        couponQuantityCtrlr: getProductDetails
                                            .couponQuantityCtrlr,
                                        couponDateFromCtrlr: getProductDetails
                                            .couponDateFromCtrlr,
                                        couponDateToCtrlr:
                                            getProductDetails.couponDateToCtrlr,
// * couponFeaturedImage is a List<dynamic>, but do contains a list of strings(url).
                                        couponFeaturedImage: getProductDetails
                                            .couponFeaturedImage,
// * couponMultipleImagesCtrlr is a List<dynamic>, but do contains a list of strings(url).
                                        couponMultipleImagesCtrlr:
                                            getProductDetails
                                                .couponMultipleImagesCtrlr,
                                      ))));
```

I do pass it and store it on my initState on my second page

```
TextEditingController? couponNameCtrlr;
  TextEditingController? couponDescCtrlr;
  TextEditingController? couponSalePriceCtrlr;
  TextEditingController? couponTypeCtrlr;
  TextEditingController? couponCategoryCtrlr;
  TextEditingController? couponOrigPriceCtrlr;
  TextEditingController? couponQuantityCtrlr;
  TextEditingController? couponDateFromCtrlr;
  TextEditingController? couponDateToCtrlr;
  TextEditingController? couponMultipleImagesCtrlr;
  TextEditingController? couponUniqueId;
  List? couponFeaturedImage;

void initState() {
    couponNameCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponNameCtrlr);
    couponDescCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponDescCtrlr);
    couponSalePriceCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponSalePriceCtrlr);
    couponTypeCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponTypeCtrlr);
    couponCategoryCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponCategoryCtrlr);
    couponOrigPriceCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponOrigPriceCtrlr);
    couponQuantityCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponQuantityCtrlr);
    couponDateFromCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponDateFromCtrlr);
    couponDateToCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponDateToCtrlr);
    couponUniqueId =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponUniqueId);
    couponSalePriceCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponSalePriceCtrlr);
    couponFeaturedImage = widget.couponFeaturedImage;
    super.initState();
  }
```

The solutions that I tried and searched here is that I past it through `StatefulWidget` using the required below it...

```
final ProductModel latestprod;
  final List? couponFeaturedImage;
  const MerchantEditProduct(
      {Key? key, required this.latestprod, this.couponFeaturedImage})
      : super(key: key);
```

However I cannot still retrieve it, I would appreciate any helps or ideas on how to solve this one.

Comment: You are passing the `couponFeaturedImage` list inside the `latestprod` model.
Use `coufonFeaturedImage = widget.latestprod.couponFeaturedImage;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by storing the couponFeaturedImage in a String variable and using setState in the `initState`.

Note: I don't know if this is the recommended fix, any ideas to improve this are welcome and appreciated! Thanks!

```
void initState() {
    couponNameCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponNameCtrlr);
    couponDescCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponDescCtrlr);
    couponSalePriceCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponSalePriceCtrlr);
    couponTypeCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponTypeCtrlr);
    couponCategoryCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponCategoryCtrlr);
    couponOrigPriceCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponOrigPriceCtrlr);
    couponQuantityCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponQuantityCtrlr);
    couponDateFromCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponDateFromCtrlr);
    couponDateToCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponDateToCtrlr);
    couponUniqueId =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponUniqueId);
    couponSalePriceCtrlr =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.latestprod.couponSalePriceCtrlr);
    couponFeaturedImage = widget.couponFeaturedImage;
    super.initState();
// here and now I can access imageURL and display it as Image!
setState(() {
      imageURL = couponFeaturedImages!.first;
    });
  }
```